# BufferedReader print input while reading in realtime

Tags: java, linux

my java method looks like this:

```
    private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    Process proc;
    try {

        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);

        }
         proc.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

If I send small commands like "ls -l" it executes the command and print the results. But I need this function to read the output from an application wich will run for days and it will print frequently output while running. So I can't wait until the application is "done", I need the output in realtime. Anyone knows how to print the output without delay? thanks for help..

Comment: Does your process have any potential to write to `stderr` as well as `stdout`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to redirect the output of the command directly to a file:

```
ls -l > ./ls.output
```

In this case you don't need to wait the end of the command. It will be the operating system to handle the output redirection to a file.

If you need also to write the output for the error you need a command like the following:

```
ls -l > ./ls.output 2> ./ls.err
```

where `./ls.output` is the normal output and `./ls.err` is the output for errors

Comment: You need to redirect stderr, too, or the process could block.

Comment: @AndrewHenle added also the redirect of stderr if needed.

Comment: For anyone reading, the redirection of `stderr` can actually be more critical for child processes started by Java code - at least `stdout` is normally buffered in the child, while `stderr` isn't.  If nothing is reading `stdout` or `stderr` from the child process, it can block while trying to write if enough output is emitted.

Comment: @AndrewHenle so it is always a good idea to redirect both outputs? (normal and error) That is enough?

Comment: In general, yes.  Or use a multiple threads in the JVM to collect both streams.  But if you know the child process doesn't produce enough output to block if you don't collect the output, you can get away without it.